# Convert the following into a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

How should i convert the following into a recursive function so that the output will also be [1, 2, 6, 24, 120]?

```
def factorial(n):
    l = []
    value = 1
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        value = value * x
        l.append(value)
    print(l)


factorial(5)
```

The following is my recursion code. I am not sure on how i should use append in the function to create the list, any suggestions?

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        L.append(1)
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)


x = int(input("Enter value of n: "))
L = []

print(factorial(x))
print(L)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: You can just google it. It's not that hard.

Comment: Downvote: This is a very common task for beginners to solve, there must be hundreds of questions covering just about every aspect of it on this site alone; did you not search at all before posting?

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical recursion, except that we append the new value in a `list` `a`:

```
def factorial(n):

    if n == 1:
        return [1]

    a = factorial(n-1)
    a.append(n*a[-1])
    return a

print(factorial(5))
```

The result: `[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n,b):
  if n==1:
    return [1]
  elif len(b)==n:
    return b
  else:
    if len(b)==0:
        b.append(1)
        factorial(n,b)
    else:
        b.append((len(b)+1)*b[len(b)-1])
        factorial(n,b)  
a = []
print f(5,a)
```